# How can I use Nokogiri to find specific text/words on a webpage?

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri, watir

I am new to nokogiri, but it looks like this would be the tool that I would use to scrape a webpage. I am looking for specific words on a webpage. The words are "Valid", "Requirements Met", and "Requirements Not". I am using watir to drive through the website. I currently have:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
```

to get the html, but I am not sure where to go from here.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can store text you get by nokogiri in variable and do a regex match against the keywords you need viz 'valid', ...

Comment: You will find it easier if the words are in a tagged element, e.g. `<p id="status"></p>`, where you can search for the element and then do `.inner_text` to grab the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Watir to drive the website, I would suggest using Watir to check for the text. You can get all the text on the page using:

```
ie.text      #Where ie is a Watir::IE
```

You could then check to see if it has those words are included (by comparing to a regex):

```
if ie.text =~ /Valid|Requirements Met|Requirements Not/
  #Do something if the words are on the page
end
```

That said, if you are looking for a specific bits of text, you can use Watir to look specifically for those elements (and avoid parsing text or html). If you can provide an HTML sample of what you are working on, we can help find a more robust solution.

Comment: This was perfect. I was over thinking it (typical me). I used a variation of the regex and now I am getting the output that I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using both. You could get the page using 'net/http' or mechanize if you just want to check for text. Anyways, you can check for text in watir with `browser.text.match 'Valid'`, same for nokogiri with `page.text.match 'Valid'`.

Comment: I tried mechanize first, but it doesn't support javascript so I am not able to "click" the button. So, I switch to watir and it is working perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to use the .text method from Justin's answer along with the standard ruby string .include? method which returns true or false.

```
if browser.text.include? /Valid|Requirements Met|Requirements Not/  
  #code to execute if text found
else
  #code to execute if text not found
end
```

This also makes it easy to have a single line validation step if that is what you are after

if using rspec/cucumber

```
browser.text.should include /Valid|Requirements Met|Requirements Not/
```

if using test:Unit

```
assert browser.text.include? /Valid|Requirements Met|Requirements Not/
```

Comment: I thought this would be possible, but when I tried I got a "can't convert Regexp into String". Is there something I am missing to allow .include? to use regex?

Comment: .include?  may not allow a regex then,  so the other methods might be easier since if you can only use a string with .include? then you'd end up with a three way OR in there which might be a bit cumbersome compared to justin's answer